# HAProxy/Docker: 502 Bad Gateway when hitting Docker container running Flask/React app

Tags: docker, flask, haproxy

I am trying to Dockerize a Flask/React web application for ease of development/collaboration, but having issues getting a proper response from the application. I am able to get the image built and Flask server started in a container, but having issues actually hitting it.

We use HAProxy to forward requests, and things work fine when I have the proxy and web server running locally. The issue has been getting docker into the mix. I believe it must be a port mapping issue, but I'm out of ideas and feel I may be missing key HAProxy/Docker subtleties. The proxy.cfg file looks as follows (with extraneous hosts not included):

```
global
 maxconn 4096
 pidfile ~/tmp/haproxy.pid

defaults
 log global
 log 127.0.0.1 local0
 log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
 mode http
 timeout connect 300000
 timeout client 300000
 timeout server 300000
 maxconn 2000
 option redispatch
 retries 3
 option httpclose
 option httplog
 option forwardfor
 option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.0


frontend dev
   bind *:8080 ssl crt ./proxy.pem

    acl allow_web path_beg /app/

    use_backend be_web if allow_web

backend be_web
 balance roundrobin
 server web_5000 localhost:5000
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.6.0

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential 

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN pip install -e ./server

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
    userportal:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
            - .:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
```

The Flask server binds to port 5000 hence the mapping. I've tried substituting the container IP address for `localhost` (e.g. `172.19.0.2:5000`) but same result.

Edit:

I tried adding the proxy as a service in the docker-compose.yml and changing the host from `localhost:5000` to `userportal_1:5000`, but this led to a 503. docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
    userportal:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - /usr/src/app/client/node_modules
            - ./client:/usr/src/app/client
            - ./server:/usr/src/app/server
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    proxy:
        image: haproxy:alpine
        volumes:
            - ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
            - ./proxy.pem:/certs/proxy.pem
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know your container IP in advance

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

At some point if you want to use HAProxy it'll more easy to make it inside docker compose to to avoir networking issues

If you dont want you may try:
haproxy.conf

```
global
  maxconn 4096
  pidfile ~/tmp/haproxy.pid

defaults
  log global
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
  mode http
  timeout connect 300000
  timeout client 300000
  timeout server 300000
  maxconn 2000
  option redispatch
  retries 3
  option httpclose
  option httplog
  option forwardfor
  option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.0


frontend dev
  bind 0.0.0.0:8080 ssl crt ./proxy.pem   // <-- change wildcard with 0.0.0.0
  acl allow_web path_beg /app/
  use_backend be_web if allow_web
  default_backend be_web                  // <-- add this line

backend be_web
  balance roundrobin
  mode http
  option forwardfor                       // <-- add this line
  option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1           // <-- add this line
  server web_5000 userportal_1:5000 check // <-- change localhost to the nane of running container "userportal_1" or the IP if you get it
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.6.0

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN pip install -e ./server

EXPOSE 5000 // <-- add this ine

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  userportal:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Try to include your HAProxy in your docker-compose.yml will help a lot

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried adding everything you listed but didn't notice any change in the result. I tried adding the proxy into the docker-compose file and running it there (which let me refer to the host as `userportal_1:5000`), but that ended up resulted in a 503 error instead of 502.

Comment: Cache may be an issue after updating. If you can and only if you're sure you can try to clear cache: `docker network prune`
`docker volume prune`